# Fatal Authentication Error when i try 'Pod Install' command

Tags: ios, cocoapods, assembla

I am trying to implement my framework library into my project using Cocoa Pods.

I found similar questions but their error messages were different from mine. Hence i am posting this question.

I successfully created pod file using `pod init` command and opened pod file in TextEditor and saved my code

The following is my Pod File Content

```
#platform :ios, '8.0'
source 'git@git.assembla.com:ioslibs.podspecs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'WatchList' do

pod 'matrix'
pod 'lego'

end
```

When i try `pod install` command at my Project's Directory, it is showing the following error.

[image: Weird Error while installing Pod]

> **Note**
>
> I gave Valid Username and Password.
>
> But it gave me the same error even
>   if i give (Wantedly) incorrect Username and Password.
>
> I hope there is no problem to do with the username and password, but i can't find what's the real problem is.

Thanks for the time.. (:

---

### **UPDATE**

When i try `pod install --verbose`

```
GaneshBabu:WatchList ganeshbabu$ pod install --verbose
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-WatchList`: (``)

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A lego
  A matrix

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing lego (1.0.0)
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/bin/git clone https://git.assembla.com/ioslibs.lego.git
     /var/folders/fw/88lq9hbs5s9f4gdw1gtkbh780000gq/T/d20160831-1150-r0nsrb
     --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0
     Cloning into '/var/folders/fw/88lq9hbs5s9f4gdw1gtkbh780000gq/T/d20160831-1150-r0nsrb'...
Username for 'https://git.assembla.com': ganeshbabu.m977981
Password for 'https://ganeshbabu.m977981@git.assembla.com': 
     fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.assembla.com/ioslibs.lego.git/'

[!] Error installing lego
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://git.assembla.com/ioslibs.lego.git /var/folders/fw/88lq9hbs5s9f4gdw1gtkbh780000gq/T/d20160831-1150-r0nsrb --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.0.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/fw/88lq9hbs5s9f4gdw1gtkbh780000gq/T/d20160831-1150-r0nsrb'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.assembla.com/ioslibs.lego.git/'


/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:122:in `rescue in execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:120:in `execute_command'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:154:in `block in executable'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:64:in `block in clone'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:153:in `block in ui_sub_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:152:in `ui_sub_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:62:in `clone'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/git.rb:30:in `download!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:82:in `block in download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:137:in `block in ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:136:in `ui_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0/lib/cocoapods-downloader/base.rb:80:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:103:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:70:in `download_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:170:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:153:in `block in uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:180:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:180:in `in_tmpdir'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:152:in `uncached_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:39:in `download'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:120:in `download_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:60:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:346:in `install_source_of_pod'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:313:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:84:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:312:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:304:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:304:in `install_pod_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:63:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:158:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:115:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:37:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:50:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.0.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: use `pod install --verbose` to see if any extra output that could help is logged

Comment: @Shubhank I'll update my Question with error message

Comment: probably recheck your credentials, we can't help unless we know it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what my pod file looks like:

May be you can cross verify with this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.0"

use_frameworks!

target 'WatchList' do

   pod 'matrix'

   pod 'lego'

end
```

Also you can cross verify the directory in which you are installing pods

Comment: My directory is Correct. You have used `use_frameworks!` since you are using Switf. I am using Objective C. Everything else is exact same.. How did you wrote your pod file (Using TextEditor or Terminal) ?

Comment: using terminal. Go to terminal. change directory to your project folder. hit "vi podfile" to edit pod file. Press "i" to insert and then type pod you want to install. After that save and pod file using escape->Shift colon->wq And run "pod install"